# Equivalent of column arithmetic for melted data

Tags: r

I have a data set in "tidy" format like this:

```
  group         type score price
1     A Fish + Chips     9     8
2     B Fish + Chips     7    20
3     C Fish + Chips     8    22
4     A        Chips     9     0
5     B        Chips     0     7
6     C        Chips     8    16
7     A        Snags     5    19
8     B        Snags     9     8
9     C        Snags    10     6
```

I would like to add some derived data which, if the data was cast into wide format, would be determined using column arithmetic (adding, subtracting, etc). I have been trying to work out how to do this without casting and melting again. In the simple example here, I would like to calculate data of type `Fish` by subtracting the `Chips` data from corresponding `Fish + Chips` data. So far I have come up with the following:

```
ddply(subset(mydata, type %in% c("Chips", "Fish + Chips")),
      .(group), summarise, type="Fish",
      score=score[type=="Fish + Chips"] - score[type=="Chips"],
      price=price[type=="Fish + Chips"] - price[type=="Chips"])
```

which gives

```
  group type score price
1     A Fish     0     8
2     B Fish     7    13
3     C Fish     0     6
```

which I can then `rbind` to the original data. Any suggestions of better approaches would be appreciated (even if that is a cast and melt).

Here is the sample data:

```
structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), type = structure(c(2L, 
 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Chips", "Fish + Chips", 
 "Snags"), class = "factor"), score = c(9, 7, 8, 9, 0, 8, 5, 9, 
 10), price = c(8, 20, 22, 0, 7, 16, 19, 8, 6)), .Names = c("group", 
 "type", "score", "price"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think yours is better but here's a non-plyr/reshape solution:

```
mydataspl <- split(mydata, mydata$type)
subs <- merge(mydataspl$"Fish + Chips", mydataspl$Chips, by= 1)
data.frame(subs[,"group", drop=FALSE], type="Fish", 
   score=with(subs, score.x-score.y), 
   price=with(subs, price.x-price.y)
           )
  group type score price
1     A Fish     0     8
2     B Fish     7    13
3     C Fish     0     6
```

Comment: I'm getting close to calling this one...doesn't look like there will be any other suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for  the base R version. I'm glad I don't seem to have missed a compellingly simple, elegant or simple alternative.